# rails scope based on models parent attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

- I have 2 models. `line_item` and `account`.
- `line_item` belongs to an `account`.
- `account` has a column `is_active`.

I'm looking for a way to write a Rails scope to find all `line_items` where their account `is_active  = true`

Something like

```
LineItem.should_display
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT**

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :should_display, -> { joins(:account).where(accounts: {is_active: true}) }
end
```

This produces the same result as adding the following class method in your LineItem model.

```
def self.should_display
  joins(:account).where(accounts: {is_active: true})
end
```

I think you can find more information in the Rails guides for Active Record Querying: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: I dont know how much more context to provide when it comes to `scopes` http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Comment: @Deekor, I wasn't familiar with this aspect of rails. I edited my response to conform to the rails syntax for scoping, but, as stated in the rails guide you linked to, it produces the same result as what I posted before.

Comment: Is using scopes prefered over jusing class methods?

Comment: @Matthias From a technical standpoint, I don't think so. But it is (apparently) a rails convention, so other developers looking at your code may expect to see queries listed as Scopes at the top of a method rather then as class methods further down. Because of this, it's probably a good idea to use them where appropriate. I actually learned about them for the first time when I was responding to this post several months ago though, so I'm definitely not the most authoritative source.